# What is a credit card sized computer more powerful than a raspberry pi but with the same community and add ons?

Tags: vb.net, mono, raspberry-pi, xamarin-studio

I am in the market for a raspberry pi or alternative. I've done quite a bit of research but I can't find a raspberry pi alternative that is both more powerful, but also has the same community and add on options. So, can anyone suggest an alternative?

Note:I want one for recreation, I.E. building a robot arm, but I also want to run a low scale server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you evaluate Intel's Galileo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love following @cnxsoft on Twitter and his blog at http://www.cnx-software.com/.

I suggest you to go to his blog and see tags like http://www.cnx-software.com/tag/development-board/ there is every week at least one new board with more and more powerful processors and lower prices... Find one that fits your needs(OS, Pins...)

I'm also not sure why this is marked with tags like "xamarin-studio" :)

Comment: I added then first as i meant to mention i am running a vb.net server through mono, or xamarin. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the right forum, the scope seems too broad. So don't be surprised if this is closed as offtopic.

Can you say what alternatives you have looked at so far?

Try looking into the following and see if they fit your requirement :

http://arduino.cc/en/ArduinoCertified/IntelGalileo

http://beagleboard.org/black

Comment: hi, i have looked at the hackberry, beagle board and a few others. However, i am asking because not many have the type of expansions as the raspberry pi, but they are far more powerful

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking of the [bananapi](http://www.bananapi.org/), or  the [hummingboard](http://www.solid-run.com/products/hummingboard/).